# Debugging in VSCode in Python, debugger does not respect the breakpoints in class

Tags: python, class, object, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am new at programming in python. I use Visual Studio Code. I have some problems with my debugger. When I debug a script, my debugger takes a break at the breakpoints in my script as it should be. But in my script I also create objects from a class. To debug methods of a class (objects created from it), I set breakpoints in the methods.
I expect the debugger to jump there and respect the breakpoints, but that does not happen. I have a really long code, so I tried to shorten it. So in my Code example I set a breakpoint inside the method definition of step(old_state,action). When debugging the script, why doesn't it stop here?

```css
DQN.py
...
...
env = PowerControl() #creates object of the class PowerControl()
..
new_state = env.step(old_state, action)



class PowerControl()
..
  def step(old_state,action)
    ...
    
    return new_state
```

`

It might have to do something with the settings in my launch.json file. It looks like this.

```css
{
    // Verwendet IntelliSense zum Ermitteln möglicher Attribute.
    // Zeigen Sie auf vorhandene Attribute, um die zugehörigen Beschreibungen anzuzeigen.
    // Weitere Informationen finden Sie unter https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Aktuelle Datei",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance for support.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the issue, but I noticed that when you defined your class you didn't have a colon at the end of it, same with when you defined your method. Also, inside of classes, the first parameter of a method is typically self.

```
DQN.py
...
...
env = PowerControl() #creates object of the class PowerControl()
..
new_state = env.step(old_state, action)



class PowerControl(): # added colon
..
  def step(self, old_state, action): # added colon and self parameter
    ...
    
    return new_state
```